# SELECT maxAmount FROM activities - SELECT COUNT(activity) FROM registrations?

Tags: php, pdo

I am working on a project that I got from school but now I've run into a problem.
The two queries I have are:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Amount FROM activities ORDER BY Id ASC';
```

and:

```
$select = 'SELECT COUNT(Activity) as Activity 
           FROM `registrations` 
           INNER JOIN activities 
                ON registrations.Activity = activities.Name 
           WHERE registrations.Activity='.$row['Name'].' 
                AND registrations.Morning/Afternoon='.$row['Morning/Afternoon'].'';
```

So what needs to happen is Amount from the $sql query - COUNT(Activity) from the $select query.

So far I got this but it doesn't work the way I want it to work:

```
<?php

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM activities ORDER BY Id ASC';
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $select = 'SELECT COUNT(Activity) as Activity 
               FROM `registrations` 
               INNER JOIN activities 
                  ON registrations.Activity = activities.Name 
               WHERE registrations.Activity=' . $row['Name'] . ' 
                  AND registrations.Morning/Afternoon=' . $row['Morning/Afternoon'] . '';

    foreach ((array)$select as $select2) {
        $maxAantal = $row['Amount'] - $select2['Activity'];
    }

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Location'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Begintime'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Endtime'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $maxAmount . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Deadline'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Morning/Afternoon'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="readActi.php?id=' . $row['Id'] . '">Read</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

$_SESSION['Id'] = $row['Id'];

?>
```

But it gives me this warning

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Activity'
```

and I can't work out how to get this fixed

Comment: print_r ($row) have you tried?

Comment: Where should I place that if I may ask?

Comment: right after the foreach...$row line

Comment: That didn't work, it just gave me all information from the table

Comment: Okay. It's used for debugging, but i'll just try to analyze the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your second query `$select` isn't executed nor fetched but only set in the variable `$select`... You just forgot to query and fetch it, that's why `$select2['Activity']` is not set.

Check your second `foreach`, I presume it should be `foreach ($db->query($select) as $select2)`

**EDIT with precisions**

In you code, you have :

```
$select = 'SELECT COUNT(Activity) as Activity 
           FROM `registrations` 
           INNER JOIN activities 
              ON registrations.Activity = activities.Name 
           WHERE registrations.Activity=' . $row['Name'] . ' 
              AND registrations.Morning/Afternoon=' . $row['Morning/Afternoon'] . '';
```

then

```
foreach($select as $select2)
```

Here `$select` is a string containing your query. By doing a foreach on it, you will simply get all the characters of the string one by one, then index `['activity']` won't exist.

Comment: I did that and then it gave me the `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` warning

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM activities ORDER BY Id ASC';
if ($db->query($sql)) {
    foreach ($db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        $select = 'SELECT COUNT(Activity) as Activity 
                   FROM `registrations` 
                   INNER JOIN activities 
                      ON registrations.Activity = activities.Name 
                   WHERE registrations.Activity=' . $row['Name'] . ' 
                      AND registrations.Morning/Afternoon=' . $row['Morning/Afternoon'] . '';
        if ($db->query($select)) {
        foreach ($db->query($select)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $select2) {
            $maxAantal = $row['Amount'] - $select2['Activity'];
        }

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Location'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Begintime'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Endtime'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $maxAmount . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Deadline'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Morning/Afternoon'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="readActi.php?id=' . $row['Id'] . '">Read</a>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
}

$_SESSION['Id'] = $row['Id'];

?>
```

Try considering this code, you must use fetchAll after querying an SQL statement in order to use foreach and you not need anymore to explicitly state it as an array.

From this:

> foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {

To this:

> foreach ($db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

---

Then this:

> foreach ((array)$select as $select2) {

To this:

> foreach ($db->query($select)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $select2) {

**EDIT: FOR BOOLEAN PROBLEM, JUST ADD AN IF STATEMENT IN EVERY FOREACH STATEMENT, SEE CODE ABOVE**

Comment: But now it gives me this error: `Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean`